# Get file from custom ContentProvider method

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I have access to an exported ContentProvider, which implements the following method (from a reversed APK):

```
  public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri paramUri, String paramString)
    throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    if (sURIMatcher.match(paramUri) == 10) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException(paramUri.getPath());
    }
    paramString = new File("/data/data/", paramUri.getAuthority() + "/files/" + paramUri.getPath());
    if (paramString.exists()) {
      return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(paramString, 268435456);
    }
    throw new FileNotFoundException(paramUri.getPath());
  }
```

How do I correctly access this method, I've tried the following:

```
myUri = "content://foo.bar/"
Bundle bundle = getContentResolver().call(myUri, "openFile", "theFile", null);
String str = bundle.toString();
Log.d("TESTING",str);
```

Which results in:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.toString()' on a null object reference
```

So it seems that I receive nothing from the content provider.

How do I correctly use the content providers method?

Comment: use `getContentResolver().ipenInputStream()`

Comment: can you elaborate a bit @pskink?

Comment: what to elaborate? just read [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) API docs - the method you have to call needs just one input parameter

Comment: Quite right, `InputStream openInputStream (Uri uri)` just needs a single parameter, the URI. But I need to define the URI, the paramString (the file) and the method (openFile). Or am I missing something?

Comment: you have the uri: `myUri`, just convert it to `android.net.Uri` and use it

Comment: Yes, I understand that I have the Uri, but with `getContentResolver().openInputStream(myUri)`, where would I define the `openFile` method and the filename?

Comment: nowhere - all you have to do is call `openInputStream`, nothing more - and of course you need to use somehow returned `InputStream` to read your `Uri` content

Comment: Sorry - you're absolutely right. It's working now. Thank you! If you want to post an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: sure, you're welcome